# Applet SQL INSERT not working in browser

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, applet

I have an applet which when I test run in Eclipse works perfectly yet when I move into the browser it doesn't seem to work.

I have read already that applets are not used much anymore but I still want to learn about them for a variety of reasons.

Here is my code. Like I said it works as intended when run in eclipse.

```
public class WPStool extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
 /**
     * 
     */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 6920052961843268403L;
 Label lblCustNum, lblCustName, lblAccount, lblEmpID, lblSuccess;
 TextField txtCustNum, txtCustName, txtAccount, txtEmpID;
 Button bEnter;
 boolean blnCorrect;

 public void init()
 {
     lblCustNum = new Label("Customer #");
  add(lblCustNum);

  txtCustNum = new TextField(20);
  add(txtCustNum);

  lblCustName = new Label("Customer Name");
  add(lblCustName);

  txtCustName = new TextField(20);
  add(txtCustName);

  lblAccount = new Label("Account Type");
  add(lblAccount);

  txtAccount = new TextField(20);
  add(txtAccount);

  lblEmpID = new Label("EmployeeID");
  add(lblEmpID);

  txtEmpID = new TextField(20);
  add(txtEmpID);

  bEnter = new Button("Enter");
  add(bEnter);
  bEnter.addActionListener(this);
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 {

  if (e.getSource() == bEnter)
    {
        //registerUser();
        int custNum = Integer.parseInt(txtCustNum.getText());
        int empID = Integer.parseInt(txtEmpID.getText());
        enterInfo(custNum, txtCustName.getText(), txtAccount.getText(), empID);
        txtCustNum.setText("");
        txtCustName.setText("");
        txtAccount.setText("");
        txtEmpID.setText("");
    }
 }



public void enterInfo(int custNuma, String custNamea, String accounta, int empIDa)
{
    Connection con = getConnection();
    try
    {
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        String select = "INSERT INTO  customerInfo (custNum , custName, account ,empID) VALUES ("+ custNuma +",  '"+ custNamea +"',  '"+ accounta +"',  "+ empIDa +")";
        //String select = "INSERT INTO  customerInfo (custNum , custName, account ,empID) VALUES (123,  'Jim John Joe',  'New Account', 1234)";
        s.executeUpdate(select);
        lblSuccess = new Label("Success!");
        add(lblSuccess);

    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("getClasses method: " + e.getMessage());
        lblSuccess = new Label("FAIL!");
        add(lblSuccess);
    }
}

private Connection getConnection()
{
    Connection con = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/wps";
        String user = "root";
        String pw = "";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pw);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("getConnection ClassNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("getConnection SQL: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return con;
}

}
```

Is there some extra browser settings I need to setup? Also. I am importing the JDBC so I can use sql, do I need to add this somehow?

Comment: you might be hitting a permission exception, as in browsers Applets are running under a security manager. You need to specify what exception you are getting so that people could help yo more effectively

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the Java Console for errors. 2) Does the DB reside on the same server as the applet?  3) Don't use AWT based components this millennium, use Swing.

Comment: lol Thanks for the tip. I had read that some people prefer the AWT over swing in browser applets but I will convert this to swing.

Comment: Also, I am not getting ANY exceptions. I have checked the error console and everything seems to work fine. As for the permissions I will have to look into that more closely. When the applet initially loads it asks for permission to run but perhaps there are more permissions that need to be set somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe from the browser the java code is not able to connect to the database.

You have to change your application structure, and separate the applet part from the server part. Put in the applet part all the user interface logic, then connect to the server part, via RMI or Web Service, sending data, and on server side connect to the database.

Another point event if your client would be able to connect to the database, if you release the applet with connection url `jdbc:mysql://localhost/wps` then every client will try to connect to a database on the same machine that run applet. That is, if you have 10 clients, every try will search for the database on itself, because you use `localhost`.

However I suggest you to separate your application login in the two part I describe you above.

Comment: Are you saying write a PHP or Javascript script to connect to DB or do you mean another java class? I am very new to Java so I hope this doesn't sound dumb.

Comment: If you know better php, write the server part with php. Then call the php page from java sending data for example in JSON.

Comment: Great answer.  +1'd with my 2nd last vote for the day (the next 3 hours, anyway).  ;)

Comment: This applet is not for anyone else to use. I am just working on it to improve my Java knowledge. But like you say, Java does not seem to be the best language to handle the SQL.

Comment: Java is ok for SQL, it is used all around the world for SQL. Are the `Applet` that are not good to handle directly SQL.

Comment: Just looked up how to send Java data through POST to php scipt...That is DEFINITELY the way to approach this.